# Concatenate all columns in a dataframe, including column name and delimiters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, concatenation

Using Python I am importing a large dataset into a Pandas Dataframe. These datasets are 10k+ rows and 1k+ columns. I need to concatenate all of the column values along with the column name and other delimiters. I have used a For loop to solve this, and it works fine, but is VERY slow and too many rows causes out of memory errors.

```
col 1     col 2     col 3...
val1      val2      val3 ...
val4      val5      val6
```

into

```
ConcatValues
Col 1=val1|Col 2=val2|Col 3=val3...
Col 1=val4|Col 2=val5|Col 3=val6...
```

My current solution looks like this, that adds a new column, "ConcatValues":

```
cols = df.columns
for col in cols[1:]:
     df["ConcatValues"] = df["ConcatValues"].astype(str) + "|" + col + "=" +  df[col].astype(str)
```

I have tried to get something like this working, using Apply and lambda:

```
df["ConcatValues"] = df[cols].apply(lambda x : str(x.name)+'='+x+"|",axis=1)
```

But this isnt concatenating the columns, just the values.

I have read several posts on similar problems, but none of those involved concatenating the column names or other characters along with the values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include a second row in your example? It's not clear (to me at least) what's supposed to happen with the rows following the first one.

Comment: please consider providing the reproducible code along with the data. here are the stackoverflow guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: OK, I added a second row of data. Basically each row of columns gets concatenated into 1 column, "ConcatValues".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```py
df['ConcatValues'] = df.apply(lambda c: f'{c.name} = '+c).agg('|'.join, axis=1)
```

output:

```
  col 1 col 2 col 3                            ConcatValues
0  val1  val2  val3  col 1 = val1|col 2 = val2|col 3 = val3
1  val4  val5  val6  col 1 = val4|col 2 = val5|col 3 = val6
```

Or, as new DataFrame:

```py
df2 = (df.apply(lambda c: f'{c.name} = '+c)
         .agg('|'.join, axis=1)
         .to_frame('ConcatValues')
       )
```

output:

```
                             ConcatValues
0  col 1 = val1|col 2 = val2|col 3 = val3
1  col 1 = val4|col 2 = val5|col 3 = val6
```

Comment: That did it! After a minor change... I was getting this error "ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype u32" , so I added ".astype(str)" to the c before the .agg: df['ConcatValues'] = df.apply(lambda c: f'{c.name} = '+c.astype(str)).agg('‡'.join, axis=1)

Also, your solution is very efficient. A 20k row sample file I had was taking 2.5 hours to complete. I just ran it using your solution and it completed in about 3 minutes! Fantastic, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC this should get you what you are expecting

```
data = {
    'Column1' : ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    'Column2' : ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    'Column3' : ['1', '2', '3', '4']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for x in df.columns:
    df[x] = df[x].apply(lambda row : f"{x}={str(y)}")
df['merge_column'] = df.apply(lambda x : '|'.join(x), axis = 1)
df = df[['merge_column']]
df.to_csv('WheverEver you want it to go', index = False, header=False)
df
```